# Scale the selected image in the gallery

Tags: android, gallery

How could i scale the selected image in the Gallery, i tried this, but it doesn't work very well. `

```
public void  onItemSelected  (AdapterView<?>  parent, View  v, int position, long id) 
{
    Animation grow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DetailTvShow.this, R.anim.grow);

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setText("saison "+(position+1));
            View sideView = v.findViewById(position + 1);
            View sideView1 = v.findViewById(position - 1);

           if ((sideView != null)||(sideView1 != null)){
               ((ImageView)sideView).setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 115));

               ((ImageView)sideView1).setLayoutParams(new `enter code here`Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 115));

           }

      /*      sideView = parent.findViewById(position + 1);
          if (sideView != null)
               ((ImageView)sideView).setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 115));  */

            v.startAnimation(grow);
            v.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(105, 140));
        }`
```

Comment: try setScaleType(ScaleType.FITXY);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, there was a similar solution to the one I will present here on stack overflow but it did not work correctly, though the views would scale, they would eventually stop returning to their original size.

Here the modified fix I found for myself that so far seems to work fine and does not cause any issues.

In res/anim create a grow.xml file *change to scale sizes to whatever works for you*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromXScale="1.0"
       android:toXScale="1.075"
       android:fromYScale="1.0"
       android:toYScale="1.075"
       android:duration="150"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
       android:fillAfter="true"> 
</scale>
```

Copy this class and put it in your inherited gallery or right in your activity

```
    private class SelectListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        private Animation grow     = null;
        private View      lastView = null; 

        public SelectListener(Context c) {
             grow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(c, R.anim.grow);
        }

        public void  onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>  parent, View  v, int position, long id)         {

            // Shrink the view that was zoomed 
            try { if (null != lastView) lastView.clearAnimation();
            } catch (Exception clear) { }

            // Zoom the new selected view
            try { v.startAnimation(grow); } catch (Exception animate) {}

            // Set the last view so we can clear the animation 
            lastView = v;
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>  parent) {
        }

   }
```

Then after you have created your gallery class and attached the adapter call

```
yourGalleryName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SelectListener(this));
```

This worked for me, let me know if it does for you as well.

Comment: @Dr. aNdRO this answer is 3 years old, you might want to add your OS that you are using and what "not working" means, etc.

Comment: Base SDK is Jellybean I working on Kitkat, Every piece of code is running but I cant see any changes. I tried to zoom it out a lil bit more but I cant see any animation thou.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help you to get on the right track:

```
public class bitmaptest extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
           R.drawable.android);

    int width = bitmapOrg.width();
    int height = bitmapOrg.height();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    // createa matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // rotate the Bitmap
    matrix.postRotate(45);

    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); 

    // make a Drawable from Bitmap to allow to set the BitMap 
    // to the ImageView, ImageButton or what ever
    BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

    // set the Drawable on the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);

    // center the Image
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);

    // add ImageView to the Layout
    linLayout.addView(imageView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
            )
    );

    // set LinearLayout as ContentView
    setContentView(linLayout);
}
```

}